# After a delay, how can I make a div disappear after being scrolled to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: just realized i don't need to wait to scroll for the delay. I could just on load make the ul in node2 continuously switch out (fade in/fade out) after every five seconds. This simplifies the problem i think.

Sorry I had trouble phrasing the question.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div style="height: 600px" id="node1">


</div>

<div style="height: 600px" id="node2">

    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

Basically once node2 has been scrolled to, i want to show the first ul and hide the second ul. After a delay of like 5 seconds I want to make the first ul fade out and the second ul fade in. Then repeat the process.

I don't really know how to combine the fact that the ul needs to be scrolled to and the delay after being scrolled to so I don't have any code for an attempted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate requirements:

- Detecting whether the user scrolled past an element or not. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can use a plugin like [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/), which already does just that.

  ```
  var firstTime = true; // we'll make sure the animation starts only once

  $('#node2').waypoint({
    // When #node2 arrives at 75% of the screen
    offset: '75%',
    handler: function(direction) {
      // If it's the first time and we're scrolling down
      if(firstTime && direction == 'down') { 
        firstTime = false;
        // Apply fading effect
        $('ul', this.element).fadingEffect();
      }
    }
  });
  ```
- Fading elements in and out. Since you mentioned jQuery in your question's tags, we'll use that and create a function that shows your `ul` elements one after the other.

  ```
  $.fn.fadingEffect = function() {
    var elements = $(this),
        total    = elements.length,
        index    = 0;

    elements.hide();

    (function next() {
      elements.eq(index)
              .fadeIn(500)
              .delay(5000)
              .fadeOut(200, function() {
                  index++;
                  if (index >= total) { index = 0; }
                  next();
              });
    })();
  };
  ```

#### Demo

For this to work, make sure you include both jQuery and Waypoints in your page before your script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .setTimeOut()

```
setTimeout(function(){ event() }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var ul=[ $('#node2 ul:nth-child(1)'),$('#node2 ul:nth-child(2)')]; 
var flag=false;
setInterval(function () {
        var show = flag?1:0;
        var hide = flag?0:1;
        ul[show].fadeIn(1000);
        ul[hide].fadeOut(1000);
        flag= !flag;
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 600px" id="node2">

    <ul>
        <li>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elite.</li>
    </ul>


</div>
```